# Subscribing to service returns `undefined` values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

I am trying to subscribe to a service which is trying to access the REST back-end using the following object.

```
export class Country {

    iso: String;
    iso3: String;
    name: String;
    niceName: String;
    numCode: number;
    phoneCode: number;

    constructor(values: Country = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

This is the service method which retrieves the data from the API, and the data is retrieved successfully into the `map()` function.

```
public getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get(COUNTRY_URL).pipe(
            map(response => {
                const countries = response.json()._embedded.countries;
                return countries.map((country) => { new Country(country) });
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

And this is the consumer subscribing to the service.

```
countries: Country[] = [];

constructor(private countryService: CountryService) {
    countryService.getCountries()
        .subscribe(countries => { 
            this.countries = countries;
    });
}
```

The `country` variable ends up being an array of `undefined` objects.

> **Additional Info**
>
> I am using **Angular 6** with **RXJS6** and followed the migration
>   guide
>   [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

This is a sample API response.

```
{
    "_embedded" : {
        "countries" : [ ... ]
    },
    "_links" : {
        "first" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries?page=0&size=20"
        },
        "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated" : true
        },
        "next" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries?page=1&size=20"
        },
        "last" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries?page=11&size=20"
        },
        "profile" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/countries"
        },
        "search" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/search"
        }
    },
    "page" : {
        "size" : 20,
        "totalElements" : 239,
        "totalPages" : 12,
        "number" : 0
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any issue with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Angular6 then you shouldn't be doing such things as `response.json()`

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Comment: Just look at what `response` is

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? `Object.assign(this, values);`

Comment: That has the same result. In fact assigning individual fields from `values` yields the same result. It might be something to do with the subscribe changes in `RXJS6.0`, but I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I just tested, by doing `Object.assign(values, this);` you assign the values of `this` object to the `values` object. So it has to be the other way around.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Did you try to log the returned array after its `map`?

Comment: It returns an array of undefined values.

Comment: I was talking about the array map, not the map operator of rxjs object.  Also, as @yurzui said, if you are using ng6 and the HttpClient service (not Http) you should not parse the response because it is already json. To begin with, you could also log `console.log(response.json()._embedded.countries)`

Comment: I am talking about the returned array after mapping. It returns an array of undefined, but the response logs fine prior to mapping.

Comment: Are you sure `console.log(countries.map((country) => { new Country(country) }))` returns fine?

Comment: That returns an array of undefined.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the `console.log(response.json()._embedded.countries)`. https://imgur.com/a/Y1LSK9o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a `return` before `new Country(country)` (or alternatively, remove the surrounding curly braces).